# Method not found: 'Void SimpleInjector.ScopedLifestyle..ctor(System.String, Boolean)'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, simple-injector, webapi

i m trying to use the simple Injector inside my web api project,
after that i got this Error

[image]

here is my SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs file :

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Argo.WebApi.App_Start.SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer), "Initialize")]

namespace Argo.WebApi.App_Start
{
    using System.Web.Http;
    using Argo.Core.Cache.Elasticsearch;
    using Argo.DataRepository.Cache.Interface;
    using Argo.Web.Api;
    using SimpleInjector;
    using SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi;
    using SimpleInjector.Lifestyles;
    
    public static class SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer
    {
        /// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as Web API Dependency Resolver.</summary>
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
            
            InitializeContainer(container);

            container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
       
            container.Verify();
            
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
                new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }
     
        private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
        {
//#error Register your services here (remove this line).

            // For instance:
            container.Register<IElasticOccurrenceCache, ElasticOccurrenceCache>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register<IBigNumbersService, BigNumbersService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        }
    }
}
```

this file was generated automatically after installing the simple injector package

```
// that is the only code i add in this file 
            container.Register<IElasticOccurrenceCache, ElasticOccurrenceCache>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register<IBigNumbersService, BigNumbersService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

i hope that is all the informations that you need , is you need more infos you can ask me in the comment and i will provide it

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can work it out from the stack trace:

SimpleInjector's `WebRequestLifestyle` class (living in SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.dll) is being newed up, and its ctor is delegating to the ctor of its base class, `ScopedLifestyle` (living in SimpleInjector.dll), which it expects to have the signature shown.

But when the runtime loads up the `ScopedLifestyle` type from the separate assembly, it doesn't find what it expects to be there - none of the available ctor signatures are right, none of them match what SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.dll said should be there.

The only two explanations are:

1. the SimpleInjector team have made a horrible mistake in their assemblies
2. or you have mismatching versions of SimpleInjector.dll and SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.dll

The best way to resolve this is to delete all your obj, bin and package folders (don't rely on VS's 'clean' functionality), make sure all your package references point to packages that *should* work together, then run nuget restore.

In fact I'd recommend removing SimpleInjector and SimpleInjector.Integration.Web completely, then only reinstalling the second one - this should automatically install a matching version of the base package.

(see here for details about the classes: https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/T_SimpleInjector_Integration_Web_WebRequestLifestyle.htm - not useful for solving but helped me in answering)

Comment: I can guarantee that option 1) is not the reason. Most likely OP is using a v4.x version of the Web package, while using v5.x of the core library.

Comment: Otherwise I made a terrible mistake ;-)